# Measure distance between two points on a LineString in Python

Tags: python, gis, shapely

I have the following problem: I have a route (as a LineString, from A to B). The route passes close to a point C1. I want to know how long the path is from point A along the route to point C1 (see image). In the JS-Package turf there is the function [nearest-point-on-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/nearest-point-on-line) which does exactly this (it calculates the length on the line as well). But is there something similar in Python?

[image: Route from A to B]

Here are two attempts I tried.

### 1. Snapping point to line, intersecting line with new point

Find next point to C1 on line = C2. Then generate new LineString by intersecting LineString with point C2. The length of this new line is length between A and C2 on the line.

```py
from shapely.ops import nearest_points, split

# Snap to line
c2 = nearest_points(line, c1)[0]

# Split line at point
splitted_line = split(line, c2)
```

#### Problem:

**The line is never cut because c2 is not on the line, even though it has been snapped. They differ by a few decimal places.**

### 2. Create line between C1 and C2, extend it, intersect with LineString

In this variation I try to intersect the LineString with a second line. As before, the next point on the line to C1 is searched for (=C2). Now I generate a LineString from C1 and C2. I increase this LineString in the direction of C2 by a fixed value. Then the route is intersected with the new LineString.

[image: Intersect with line]

```py
import cmath
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import nearest_points, split, LineString

# This function expands the line in given direction.
def expandLineInDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2, dist):
    # calculate the x,y change between the points
    difference = complex(x2,y2) - complex(x1,y1) 

    # convert the difference to polar coordinates
    (distance, angle) = cmath.polar(difference) 

    #calculate a new x,y change based on the angle and desired distance
    displacement = cmath.rect(dist, angle) 

    # add the displacement to the start and end point
    xy3 = displacement + complex(x2,y2)  

    x3 = xy3.real
    y3 = xy3.imag
    return (x3, y3)

# This function will split the line with a line that is build with two points and extended
def getLineLengthFromPointOnLine(line, p1, p2):
    # p1 = unsnapped
    # p2 = snapped
    # p3 = will be calculated. Expand the line so that it cross the original line on all cases

    cuttingLine = LineString([p1, expandLineInDirection(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, 2)])

    result = split(line, cuttingLine)
    
    if len(result.geoms) < 2:
        #print("Split hat nicht funktioniert, nicht zwei Linien")
        return -1

    return result.geoms[0].length

point_length = getLineLengthFromPointOnLine(line, c1, c2)
```

#### Problem

This works most of the time - but not always. **In a few rare cases it is possible that the new line does not intersect the LineString (see picture)**.

[image: New Line never touches other line]

Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: It should be `splitted_line = split(line, c2).geoms[0]`. Does that fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for the closest point along the various segments and use the matching point to indicate where to split.

```
import shapely as shp
import itertools as it

line_coords = [[0, 0], [0, -2], [5, -2], [7, -4]]
line = shp.LineString(line_coords)
pt = shp.Point(4, -1)

closest_pt = shp.ops.nearest_points(line, pt)[0]

segments = [shp.LineString([a,b]) for a,b in it.pairwise(line_coords)]
closest_segment_pts = [shp.ops.nearest_points(seg, pt)[0] for seg in segments]
match = closest_segment_pts.index(closest_pt)

split_line = shp.LineString(line_coords[0:match+1] + [[closest_pt.x, closest_pt.y]])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this calculates the route from the start to the nearest vertice. However, I am looking for the length from start to the point **on the line**.

Comment: That was my intention, but I slipped up on the last line. This should be fixed now.